# How to add extension attributes to Customer entity in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, extensions, magento-2.0

I am trying to add extension attributes to customer entity.

I set `extension_attributes.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="my_attribute" type="Text">
            <join reference_table="my_entity"
                  reference_field="customer_id"
                  join_on_field="entity_id">
                <field>my_entity_attribute</field>
            </join>
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

The table `my_entity` exists and it has a column called `customer_id` and I want to join this field to the `entity_id` field in the `customer_entity` table, and add `my_entity_attribute` value as the ultimate extension attribute to customer.

What am I doing wrong?

To test this, I am doing a GET rest api call to endpoint `customers/me` and debugging `$this->_getExtensionAttributes()` inside `\Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getExtensionAttributes()`, but it gives null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `Text` is not valid, use `string` instead. Then remember to clear `var/generation`, `var/cache` and `var/di`, to have changes applied.

Also see [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92054/697) to get understanding what actions are required to get extension attribute loaded during `get` and `getList`. Join directive will work for `getList` only.

Comment: Hi Alex P I have all you suggested using `string`, clearing all the `var` dir, and compiling it using `bin/magento setup:di:compile`. The file `var/generation/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/CustomerExtension.php` is created correctly. However I cannot see the `extension_attributes` in the API call and I still get `null` when calling $this->_getExtensionAttributes() inside `\Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getExtensionAttributes()`. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Plugins should be added to populate extension attributes. Please read comments to my answer in another post.

Comment: Ok, but I do not see the purpose of the extension attributes then. Shouldn't I just go only with the plugin?

Comment: If the goal is to make field accessible via REST, then yes, it is mandatory. One of the reasons for extension attributes introduction, was to make it possible to extend web APIs. As soon as you declare extension attributes, they will become visible in WSDL (SOAP) and REST documentation. Unknown fields will be just filtered out by web API during request/response processing.

Comment: Ok it makes sense.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: you always need to create a plugin as well? Just creating an EAV-attribute in your setup script and declaring it in your `extension_attributes.xml` doesn't make it visible for `getExtensionAttributes()`?

Comment: That seems to be the case.