# Magento 2 - Best practice for extending customer entity

Tags: magento2, customer, eav, customer-attribute, extension-attributes

I'm looking for the best practice for extending the customer entity. 
I want to add some custom fields (user_name, company_infos, etc.) and I don't know if it's better to extend the customer entity with the new attributes or creating a new table to store the additional data. The goal is to visualize the custom data on the product detail page. 
So what do you think, which is better the solution to get the best performance?

Thanks.

Marco

**Update:**
I followed the hints below, but the extension Attribute won't be saved. 
Do you have any suggestions to solve it?

I created an extension_attributes.xml file:

```
<config>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="user_name" type="string">
           <join reference_table="customer_extension" reference_field="customer_id" join_on_field="entity_id">
              <field>user_name</field>
           </join>            
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

And an Observer which is registered on the "customer_register_success" event:

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterCustomerSaveObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_logger;
    protected $_customerExtensionFactory; 
    protected $_customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory $customerExtensionFactory
    ) {

        $this->_logger = $logger;

        $this->_logger->addDebug('AfterCustomerSaveObserver_Constructor_Begin');

        $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_customerExtensionFactory = $customerExtensionFactory;


        $this->_logger->addDebug('AfterCustomerSaveObserver_Constructor_End');
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $this->_logger->addDebug('AfterCustomerSaveObserver_Execute_Begin');

/*      try { */

            $event = $observer->getEvent();
            $customer = $event->getCustomer();  

            $customerExtension = $customer->getExtensionAttributes(); 
            if ($customerExtension === null) { 
                $customerExtension = $this->_customerExtensionFactory->create(); 
            }       
            $customerExtension->setUserName("Test123"); 
            $customer->setExtensionAttributes($customerExtension); 

            $this->_customerRepository->save($customer);
            //$customer->save();

/*      } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e);
        } */

        $this->_logger->addDebug('AfterCustomerSaveObserver_Execute_Begin');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better to create separate table and use extension attributes mechanism (as described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92054/697)). Then access these attributes via `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface::getExtensionAttributes()`.

Comment: Thx for the Information. It helps me to get deeper into Extension Attributes.
But how can I save the Extension Attributes? In my case I created an Observer which should save the Extension Attributes after saving the customer registration.

Comment: Attribute value should be saved in plugin declared for customer repository save method, no need to create observer.

Comment: I want to extend the customer registration form. How do I get the value of my "user_name" textfield, which I want to store in the extended attribute?

Comment: That's a separate question related to forms, I would recommend to ask it separately.

Comment: Ok but how do I save the extension attribute? Is it right in the observer on top?

Comment: It is up to you how to save them, but recommended way is using plugins. See [why](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93932/magento-2-plugin-vs-observer/93964#93964)

Comment: In other words:
Is it the right way to use the setExtensionAttributes method of the entity and save the entity with the repository class of the entitiy?

Comment: In controller you should set extension attribute value taken from the form. Then in plugin for repository save, you should get this value and save it to custom table.

Comment: Ok thanks for the additional Explanation. 
Is there a Repository for the Extension Attributes generated too? Or how do I save the values to my custom table?

Comment: Logic for saving attribute data to table should be implemented, see `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin\AroundProductRepositorySave::aroundSave` as an example.