# Magento 2: How to add a custom attribute to the CMS Page

Tags: magento2, cms, eav, custom-attributes

I am trying to add a custom attribute to a CMS page in Magento 2.

As it seems there is no way of using EAV, since the Page model does not have entity types.

I tried to add an Extension Attribute, and using a preference for the CMS Page form, like described in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92054/37594) and added a field to the CmsPage edit form, but I can't get the plugin for the save functionality in `PageRepositoryInterface` to work.

The Extension Attribute is added as follows in etc/extension_attributes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface">
    <attribute code="slider" type="VanOns\Slider\Api\Data\SliderInterface[]"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

The plugin for the PageRepositoryInterface in etc/di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="pageAroundSave" type="VanOns\Slider\Model\Plugin\AroundPageRepositorySave"/>
</type>
```

If I use a logger in my aroundSave function, it won't log anything, suggesting it doesn't pass this function.

Any idea's on how to fix this?